# Replace text with on page load

Tags: javascript

I know how to replace text with `getElementById()` function in such situation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function go(){
        var p = document.getElementById('ccc');
        p.firstChild.nodeValue = 'AAA';
    }
</script>

<div id='ccc'>o</div>

<a href="javascript:go()">go</a>
```

When I click on go link 'o' replaces on 'AAA'.

But I want to replace text when page loading to browser without any clicking. So user do not have to know that there was some text 'o' in div 'ccc'. He must see only 'AAA' from the beginning.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use onload attribute like this:
`<body onload="go()">`

Comment: But if there will be more than one replacement functions how to call all that functions in body tag?

Comment: `onload="go(); go2(); go3()"`, but I don't recommend it. It's always cleaner to separate the HTML from the JavaScript!

Comment: You may wrap calls to them all one function or use solution proposed by ComFreak

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `onload` event:

```
window.onload = go;

// or better
window.addEventListener("load", go);
```

You can also use an anonymous function:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  // ...
}
window.addEventListener("load", function()
{
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

handle window.onload event, it fires up when the page loads.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doLoad() {
   go1();
   go2();
   // ...
}

if ( window.addEventListener ) { 
   window.addEventListener( "load", doLoad, false );
}
else 
   if ( window.attachEvent ) { 
      window.attachEvent( "onload", doLoad );
} else 
       if ( window.onLoad ) {
         window.onload = doLoad;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You do not even need to wrap `go()` into another function!

Comment: that's just for convenience =)

Comment: Hmmm, yes if you ever need to add a function ;)

Comment: the convenience here is that installing event handlers code is separated from event handlers themselves. that way it makes it easy to support in future.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can just put your script at the bottom of the page, all elements will be loaded then.

```
<div id='ccc'>o</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var p = document.getElementById('ccc');
    p.firstChild.nodeValue = 'AAA';
</script>
```